# how do i union int? and int variables in linqpad

Tags: linq, linqpad

In LinqPad 
Getting the following error trying to union int? and int variables
Researched but can't find a solution that seems to work.

CS1929 'IQueryable<>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Union<>(ParallelQuery<>, IEnumerable<>)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<>'

```
//Parent not null
var parent =
from s in Students
where s.Id==5027
select new { 
    ID_PK = s.CaseOwnerIdAspnet_Users.User_ID_FKDYN_User_Profile.Organization_ID_FKDYN_Organization.Parent_ID_FK == null ?
    s.CaseOwnerIdAspnet_Users.User_ID_FKDYN_User_Profile.Organization_ID_FKDYN_Organization.ID_PK
    :
    s.CaseOwnerIdAspnet_Users.User_ID_FKDYN_User_Profile.Organization_ID_FKDYN_Organization.Parent_ID_FK
    };

var orgs = 
from o in DYN_Organizations
join p in parent on o.Parent_ID_FK equals p.ID_PK
select new {ID_PK = o.ID_PK};

parent.Union(orgs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose parent is returning `int?` and orgs is returning `int`, then you can change orgs to return int? by casting the value, eg

change it to

```
var orgs = 
from o in DYN_Organizations
join p in parent on o.Parent_ID_FK equals p.ID_PK
select new {ID_PK = (int?) o.ID_PK};
```

Your error message also mentions ParallelQuery and IEnumerable and I'm not sure if you can create a union between this types. If not, then the easiest way is to add `.ToList()` to the end of each query and then you are creating a union between two Lists which will work.

Comment: select new {ID_PK = (int?) o.ID_PK};

This did the trick, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: in the initial parent query if `Parent_ID_FK` is `int?` then you can use the property`.HasValue` instead of checking for `null`.  Also to get the actual int value use the `.Value` property.  Then you'll have `int` values and not `int?`